# How do I change the way my data is presented in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

My data is currently presented as a frequency table of age and gender sorted by each region (as follows as an example of a couple of rows)

| Region | age | gender | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | M | 114 |
| 1 | 0 | F | 87 |
| 1 | 1 | M | 36 |
| 1 | 1 | F | 54 |

It is a large data set and has 500 regions and data for males and females aged 0-55. I am wanting to present the data with each region as one row, with total male and female populations being split into separate columns. It would also help to be able to have columns showing total population <30 and total population >=30 for each region.
e.g.:

| Region | M | F | Total | <30 | >=30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 215 | 365 | 200 | 165 |
| 2 | 85 | 75 | 160 | 95 | 65 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have been migrated to Stack Overflow, welcome! Do you mind to work through our brief tutotial on [how to make reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038)? I'm sure we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tidyverse` you could do something like this (not tested on your actual data)...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Region) %>%
   summarise(M = sum(population[gender == "M"]),
             F = sum(population[gender == "F"]),
             Total = sum(population),
             under30 = sum(population[age<30]),
             over30 = sum(population[age>=30]))
```

If you've got any missing data, you might want to add `na.rm = TRUE` as an option in the `sum` statements.